# Using a value from an observable in an Angular Component

Tags: angular, rxjs

Typically you would be able to subscribe to an observable:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `<button (click)="someFunction()">Click me!</button>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  aProperty: boolean;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.aProperty = true;
  }

  someFunction() {
    this.store.someObservable$.subscribe((data) => {
      if (this.aProperty && data) {
         // do something
      }
    });
  }

  // unsubscribe from the subscription in OnDestroy
```

But I've read that it's best avoid to interrupt the 'flow' of a subscription. Also, can I be sure that when calling 'someFunction' it will get the data from someObservable$ at that point in time?

So I was thinking maybe in the lines of:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `<button (click)="someFunction()">Click me!</button>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  aProperty: boolean;
  data = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.store.subscribe(this.data);
    this.aProperty = true;
  }

  someFunction() {
    if (this.aProperty && this.data.getValue()) {
       // do something
    }
  }

  // unsubscribe from the subscription in OnDestroy
```

What would be the best approach? Since it's a common use-case I'm looking for an idiomatic way of doing this.

Comment: It seems that the question is not clear. Could you elaborate on what is not clear?

Comment: `can I be sure that when calling 'someFunction' it will get the data from someObservable$ at that point in time?` No, but that's not what it's meant for. Observables work asynchronously, so it can complete in a milisecond, 5 minutes or an hour.

Comment: How exactly is the second snippet related to the first? It's not calling `someFunction` at all...

Comment: Thank you. 'someFunction' is just an example, it could be called when clicking on a button in the template for example. The main point would be, that 'someFunction' can be triggered synchronously. Updated the answer to be clearer.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` can store the current value for access later, so it's obviously your best here.

Comment: I've found it difficult to find examples using this implementation. I've seen examples where the observable was converted to a promise which feels like an anti-pattern. Also I've been looking into the [angular documentation on Observables & RxJS](https://angular.io/guide/observables), but did not find an good example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use RxJS pipes to deal with unsubscriptions. Let's say you only want to use the first data emitted from your Observable, and only this one, you can use :

```
someFunction() {
this.store.someObservable$
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe((data) => {
       if (this.aProperty) {
       // do something
    }
 });
}
```

This way of doing things ensure the unsubscription from the observable, avoiding you the painfull creation of a subscription and it's unsubscription  in the ngOnDestroy().

link to the lib: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/first

Comment: But this would mean only the first would emit, and not future changes to someObservable$ right? I do want it to respond to future updates.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, *if we want to use the stream's values inside TS*, we subscribe (in ngOnInit for example) and assign to a static value.

```
data: any;
destroyer$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
    someStream$.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyer$)
    ).subscribe(val => this.data = val);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyer$.next();
}

someFunction() {
    if(this.data) // doSomething();
}
```

That's a pattern you can use in any project using RxJS, not necessarily an Angular one. More idiomatic is to use the `async` pipe inside the template, and not bother with subscriptions, cleanup etc., letting Angular elves take care of all that.

```
<child-component [someInput]="someStream$ | async"></child-component>
```